# What's the difference between "Error number" and "SQLSTATE CODE"?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

In this link below, I see `Error number`s and `SQLSTATE code`. I am wondering the difference between those two.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/en/server-error-reference.html

For example from the link above,

> Error number: **1005**; Symbol: ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE; SQLSTATE: **HY000**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page you linked to has a link to a nearby documentation page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/error-message-elements.html

> - Error code: This value is numeric. It is MySQL-specific and is not portable to other database systems.
> - SQLSTATE value: This value is a five-character string (for example, '42S02'). SQLSTATE values are taken from ANSI SQL and ODBC and are
>   more standardized than the numeric error codes.

The difference is the first is invented by MySQL, and the latter conforms to ANSI SQL.